# Style different characters inside ::after content

Tags: css

I want to style only one character inside the content of an ::after. Is it possible? Considering that the div has content inside.

In this example I want the "↵" to be **bold**. But not the "press ENTER" text.

```
.div::after {
  content: "press ENTER ↵";
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #5a5b8d;
}
```

Comment: not possible to give style this particular

Answer (score 2):

If there is no other text in the button, you could split your text in between the `before` and `after`:

```css
.button {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #5a5b8d;
}
.button::before {
  content: "press ENTER";
}
.button::after {
  content: " ↵";
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="button"></div>
```

Comment: That only works if there is no content in  the button itself.

Comment: @MrLister yeah I assumed there wasn't but should have asked for clarification, updated answer to reflect that

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to style certain characters in pseudo elements

Comment: What if its a div and not a button? That would make it go left and right.

Comment: Err, the example uses a div

Comment: Which the answer states - if there is no content...  Perhaps if you wanted a full solution you should show your html markup too in a [mcve] instead of making us guess at what your html is

Comment: @Nifel If this answer clashes with your requirements, please update the question. Nobody can solve problems you have if you don't tell us them.

Answer (score 1):

It's crazy, but this will work. Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lf8xvcyq/1/

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="button"></button>
```

**CSS:**

```
.button {
  /* Your normal CSS */
}

.button::first-letter {
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}

.button::after {
  unicode-bidi:bidi-override;
  direction:rtl;
  content: "↵ RETNE sserp";
  font-size: 11px;
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: This is wonderful. It won't work on all browsers though. Shame.

Comment: It reverses the text first. Then it uses the CSS property first-letter to target the icon you want to make bold.

Comment: This is so weird.

Comment: @Nifel I have updated this to reflect your edit. "Considering that the div has content inside"

Answer (score -1):

You can consider flexbox and the `order` property in case you will have content then you will be able to use both pseudo element:

```css
button {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #5a5b8d;
  display:flex;
}
button::before {
  content: "press ENTER";
  order:1;
  padding:0 2px; /*flexbox erase whitespace so we add padding*/
}
button::after {
  content: "↵";
  padding:0 2px;
  font-weight:bold;
  order:1;
}
```

```html
<button >some content</button>
```